# How to replace the content of a specific column with awk?

Tags: linux, text-processing, awk, replace

Given: there are 40 columns in a record. I want to replace the 35th column so that the 35th column will be replaced with the content of the 35th column and a "$" symbol. What came to mind is something like:

```
awk '{print $1" "$2" "...$35"$ "$36...$40}'
```

It works but because it is infeasible when the number of column is as large as 10k. I need a better way to do this.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You can do like this:

```
awk '$35=$35"$"'
```

Answer (score 17):

There are probably more efficient ways to do this. With that caveat:

```
awk '{$35 = $35"$"; print}' infile > outfile
```

Answer (score 10):

To reserve the original Field-Seprator, I did this. 
The column I wanted to blank-out was number $12.

```
awk -F"\t" '{OFS=FS}{ $12="" ; print   }' infile.txt > outfile.txt
```

With `gawk -i` , if you have it,you can edit the file in place.

Comment: `BEGIN {OFS=FS}` to do it only once

Answer (score 4):

If the field delimiter is `<space>`:

```
sed 's/  */$&/35'
```

Comment: If the field delimiter is unknown: `sed 's/./$&/35'`

Comment: @Underverse - I don't think that's the same thing. That should prefix the 35th char on an input line w/ the char `$` - delimited or not. The thing above should affix the 35th occurrence of any number of delimiter chars - in other words, the 35th field - with the char `$` - no matter how chars are in each field.

Comment: Ah, "40 columns in a record". I read 'the 35th column' as literally 'the 35th character column of the text file'.

Answer (score 1):

Had issues using the "approved" answers, it would replace more than just the first column in the file. I use this generic command:

```
awk '$[column]="[replace]"' FS=, OFS=, inputfile > outputfile
```

Where:

- `[column]` = column you want to change starting with 1 (not 0)
- `[replace]` = text you want to replace

Comment: `awk '$1=mktime($1)' FS=, OFS=, oldfile > newfile`  ... replaced a million timestamps in a few seconds!! :)