# How to replace the content of specific column with awk? Tab Delimited File

Tags: text-processing, awk, replace

Here's a similar question but I ran into a problem that was not addressed in the question.
[How to replace the content of a specific column with awk?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/136322/how-to-replace-the-content-of-specific-column-with-awk)

I want to do something similar, however my file is tab delimited instead of space delimited.  I want to change field 3. Lets say my file looks like this:

```
NAME\tNUMBER\tID\tSEQ\t...\t...\t...
```

Lets say I want to change field 3 to AD

```
awk '{$3 = "AD"; print}' infile > outfile
```

my output is

```
NAME\tNUMBER\tAD SEQ ... ... ... ... ... ...
```

my tabs turn into spaces after the replaced 
I'm sure I can just `tr` the output file but I want to know what causes `awk` to change the field delimiter.

expected output:

```
NAME\tNUMBER\tAD\tSEQ\t...\t...\t...\t
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set `O`utput `F`ield `S`eparator, to tab `\t`:

One way to do it is with `-v` option:

```
awk -vOFS='\t' '{$3 = "AD"; print}' file
```

another possibility inside `awk`, say in the BEGIN block:

```
awk 'BEGIN{OFS="\t"}{$3 = "AD"; print}' file
```

If you don't set `OFS`, then `awk` by default uses single space as a field separator.